# iPhone 5 Optimization

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I use this code in "viewDidLoad" to check if app is running on iPhone 5 or regular iPhone.

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if(result.height == 480)
    {
        // iPhone Classic

        [_backgr setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"usefull_i4.png"]];
        [scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(16, 69, 291, 349)];
        [_backgr setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];


    }
    if(result.height == 568)
    {
        // iPhone 5
        [_backgr setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"usefull_i5.png"]];
        [scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(15, 111, 295, 349)];
        [_backgr setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];

    }
}
```

It doesn't work. :( Only if I change !here from iPhone 3.5 to iPhone 4, this code work. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzdVU.jpg)

Also I use this code for another ViewController and works great.. I don't use Autolayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this macro : (in .pch file)

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

Example :

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    if(IS_IPHONE_5)
    {
         // code
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work.. it stretch the image... exactly this code worked for the same project in another viewcontroller

Comment: Thanks anyway. I fixed. The problem was in Autosizing UIImageView.